# Accessing a template stack using operator[]

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, operators

I am building a stack using arrays (my teacher won't let me use std containers), and I am stuck. Even though I redefine the access operator `[]`, when I push, the program suddenly stops. (I implemented both copy constructor, operator = and the destroyer, bur for readability I omitted those methods).

```
template <typename T>
class stack{
private:
   unsigned int _capacity;  //capacità massima
   unsigned int _size;      //dimensione attuale
   T* _stack;
public:
    stack()
    : _capacity(10), _size(0), _stack(0){}
    T& operator[](unsigned int _index)  
        {
           assert(_index < _size);
           return _stack[_index];
        }
void push (const T &value){
    if (_size == _capacity){    //double the stack dimension
        if(_capacity==0)
            _capacity=10;
        _capacity *= 2;
        T* tmp = new T[_capacity];
        copy_n(_stack, _size, tmp);
        swap(_stack, tmp);
        delete[] tmp;
    }
    _stack[_size] = value;
    ++_size;
}

void print(){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
        cout << _stack[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

My main is simple:

```
int main(){
    stack<int> s;
    s.push(2);
    s.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_capacity(10), _size(0), _stack(0)`, with `stack == nullptr`, how `capacity` can be `10` ?

Comment: `if (_size == _capacity)` is never true for a newly created `stack` as `_capacity` is `10` and `_size` is `0`. Therefore you never allocate an array for `_stack`

Comment: A `stack` shouldn't have a `operator[]`.  It is a FIFO data structure and the only thing available should be the "top" and you can `push` and `pop` it.

Comment: @NathanOliver that was clear to me, the [ ] is to perform the push action, since i am implementing it with an array it would be impossible otherwise

Comment: @man_o_war Your `push` function does your pushing.  You don't need to define a `operator[]` to help with that.  `_stack[_size] = value;` doesn't use your `operator[]` but instead uses the `operator[]` that is defined for pointers.

Comment: @NathanOliver okay, I did that maybe because i was not getting the point, was just a trial. Anyway after few trials it worked, Thank you all

Comment: @man_o_war After changing `: _capacity(10), _size(0), _stack(0){}` to `: _capacity(0), _size(0), _stack(0){}` [it works just fine for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3f010632942d961).

Comment: `_capacity(10)` ==> `_capacity(0)`

Answer (score 0):

When you write your own Stack class, keep that in mind. If you want to ensure your value was actually inserted, implement a `top()` function that returns the value at `stack[top]`. Check `top()` after every `push()`.
That being said, in your case `_stack[_size] = value;` does not use the `operator[]`

Comment: Yes, the top() method is already implemented, but for better readability i omitted